# Is adding multiple search buttons to the same filter a bad User Experience?

Tags: gui-design, search, filter, guidelines, search-results

I am working on [shopless](https://shopless.co.nz) e-commerce website. We have multiple filters on the left hand side and the search result appears on the right:

[image]

So users can change the filter values on the left and then press on search button to update the result. Now the problem is when the filter becomes too long the user cannot see the search button at the bottom and have to scroll down to be able to click on the search button.

So we have change our design to appear like this:

[image]

Now we have 2 search buttons on the side so users don't have to scroll.

---

We have not released this new design yet, I wanted to get some UI feedback on this design, and if this is actually a better approach then we would release it.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina: You have removed the link to my website, I wanted people to be able to see the working site, so they get a better feel for the question. Is it violating this community's rules to add a link the the website in the question?

Comment: Website promotion is not a good practice here. If I’m wrong, someone will approve your new edit. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: I have not requested any new edit, this is my own question, I am able to edit without any approval. From what I can see on the website meta data, adding a working example is a plus.

Comment: It is alright. We are able to understand from the images where the problem lies. Images are always better than links because links are likely to turn dead at some point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having one save button at the end of all filter options. It would avoid unnecessary confusion for a user. Also, it demands extra space which makes the list much longer. If the lists are more than 2 scrolls, consider grouping few of them & make it expandable. Users feel a bit uncomfortable to scroll more than 3 times. Unless it's information-heavy websites like Wikipedia & Amazon.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple search buttons is confusing, my suggestion would be to have the search button always be at the bottom of the view and have the filter items scroll.

Example: The yelp iOS app search filter screen
[image: screenshot of the Yelp iOS app search result filter screen]

Comment: Thank for your answer, I hear you about having multiple buttons. Though not 100% sure about having a wide fixed button at the bottom of the page. I think it should be clear that search button is tied to the filter.

Comment: Agreed, the button should only fill the bottom of the filter side bar. The example image just happened to be a modal view instead of a sidebar so it was wider.

Comment: Also it does not need to be at the bottom of the screen if there are only a few filters (in that case it could be right under the filters).

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s a bit confusing. People may think, “Are the search buttons only for those particular filter sections?” Not that it matters.

What if you broke out the true search pieces: location and looking for, and use the search icon, then have your filter section in a new “card” or area and use an “Apply” button?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not following your suggestion. Are you able to add a basic screenshot please?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, don't go with two search buttons. Very confusing for the user. Which search should I press will be what they think? Use a single search button and make it fixed to the bottom of the screen. Also "Looking for" as a placeholder and title are confusing... Looking for what, jobs, pay rise, part-time work? If this is job titles the placeholder should be "Enter Job Title" and the title should be "Search Jobs" or something like that. Be specific, otherwise, it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a difference between the first and second button. It seems the real search button is the second category while the first one is *apply* or *update* settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer... IMO this would be more confusing than having 2 search buttons, because now we have two buttons doing the same thing but looking different.